# How can I get a call back to modify a string?

Tags: string, callback

write a function named `speaker` that takes in an array of strings and a callback function.

Use `forEach` to build a new array of strings, each string modified by the callback. Return the new array.

const speaker = (words, callback) => {

};

Honestly have zero clue where to start

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please tag the language/framework you are using so the others can help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want to write a function in JavaScript. It can be implemented like this:

```js
const speaker = (words, callback) => {
  let modifiedWords = [];
  words.forEach((word) => {
    // Add the modified string to the array
    modifiedWords.push(callback(word));
  });
  return modifiedWords;
};
```

To begin with, we define an array `modifiedWords`, where after each iteration we will add the modified word with the callback function. Next, we use the `forEach` method for the `words` array. This method iterates over each element of the array and calls the callback function that we passed (we passed an anonymous arrow function that takes an array element as an argument and passes this element as an argument to our callback function and returns the result). The result is stored in the array `modifiedWords` with the `push` method. We then return an array of modified words `modifiedWords`.